# how to show all views in databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I used

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] [[GLOBAL] TEMPORARY] VIEW
```

to create some views. And I want to show all views.

The command below does not work.

```
  show views
```

But when i used

```
 show tables
```

The result include the view.
I am so confused

Answer (score 1):

You can use `show views in database` command to get the views in the database.

[image]

If the database don't contains any views it will results ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- `SHOW VIEWS;`
- `SHOW VIEWS FROM DATABASE;`
- `SHOW VIEWS IN DATABASE;`

These all queries will work for the Databricks-DeltaLake cluster, it will not for The Databaricks cluster.